# Three.js - how to create mirror image for the entire scene

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, orientation, stereo-3d

so I'm building an AR headset that uses stereo rendering to create 3d images. 
The only problem is that when the image reflects off the headset's reflectors it creates a flipped (mirror) image. 
I need to take account for that in my Three.js code so I was wondering if there are 2 options:

1. Flip every 3d object in the scene
2. Or flip the camera to simulate an optically inverted (mirror image) camera

I'll post the basics of my code here:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

const stereo = new THREE.StereoCamera();

function render() {

   //stereo rendering code 
   camera.updateWorldMatrix();
   stereo.update(camera);

   const size = new THREE.Vector2();
   renderer.getSize(size);
   renderer.setScissorTest(true);
   renderer.setScissor(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
   renderer.setViewport(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
   renderer.render(scene, stereo.cameraL);

   renderer.setScissor(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
   renderer.setViewport(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
   renderer.render(scene, stereo.cameraR);

   renderer.setScissorTest(false);
 }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

I've also attached some images to explain what my goal is:
[image: This is currently what is being rendered with the code above]

[image]

It might be easy to just flip the cube using a matrix but what if dozens of more 3d objects get added to the scene?
Ideally, I'd like it if the entire camera could be flipped to simulate a mirrored image for the entire scene with respect to the stereo camera (if possible).

I would appreciate any help. It's also worth noting that I've tried manually flipping the display through Window's display settings but that did not have the outcome I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just use CSS to flip the element you're using to render the scene?

```
<style>
  canvas {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
</style>
```